# Как правильно преобразовать все текстовые ссылки в нужные html теги

Tags: php

Имеется textarea в которую записываются текст + ссылки на сайты и/или картинки в текстовом формате.
Вся эта история отправляется в бд. Потом достаю с бд и обрабатываю
Пример:

```
текст ... site.ru ... site.ru/jpg,png
```

Таких ссылок может быть несколько штук в тексте. А  текст может вообще отсутствовать
Написал функцию

```
function show_link ($str) 
{
    if (preg_match('~https?.+(jpg|jpeg|png)~', $str)) 
    {
        return preg_replace('~https?.+(jpg|jpeg|png)~', '<img class="img_link" src="$0">', $str, 1);
    }
    elseif (preg_match('~(http[s]*:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+)\/*([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\/\&\=\?\%]*)~', $str)) 
    {
        return preg_replace('~(http[s]*:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\.\_\-]+)\/*([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\/\&\=\?\%]*)~', '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$2</a>', $str, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return $str;
    }
}
```

В этом коде есть 2 беды
1. если в тексте есть только одна ссылка на сайт или на картинку, то все ок. Но, если вставить ссылку и на сайт и на картинку, то отображается только картинка.
2. если в тексте есть только ссылки (две и более) на сайты или на картинки, то корректно отображается только первая ссылка, а остальные это просто текст.
Нужно найти все ссылки которые есть в тексте и записать в теги.
Ребят, помогите решить задачу.
Гугл ничего подобного не выдал. Мб плохо искал..

Comment: Смотрите preg_match_all

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov сама функция без универсальной регулярки которая обработает ссылки это пустое место) и как правильно написать эту регулярку вообще без понятия...

Comment: У вас уже есть регулярное выражение, и ограничение функции которую вы используете в том, что она находит только самое первое совпадение. preg_match_all находит их все, единственное что вам нужно убрать ~ чтобы не проверяла на начало строки. Можете использовать что-то вроде regex101.com для составления и проверки выражения.